# Parallel make builds for parallel serverless deployments, errors STDOUT

Tags: serverless

I have a mono repo that has multiple serverless deployment stacks. From codebuild, we are doing all deployments. And currently with a make file we are running the deployment. Deployments are successful.

To speed up the deployments, I plan to run these sls deployments parallelly as they are independent of each other. So created a make target for each deployment and created another target with all these independent targets as prerequisites and run parallel make builds with make -j option. Here I face errors like below

Makefile

```
all-deploy: sls1 sls2 sls3

sls1:
  cd backend && sls deploy -c /path/to/sls1-config

sls2:
  cd backend && sls deploy -c /path/to/sls2-config

sls3:
  cd backend && sls deploy -c /path/to/sls3-config
```

And invoke the deployment from a bash file like

```
make -j3 all-deploy
```

Error

```
Error: STDOUT: 
  
  STDERR: find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/numpy/core/__pycache__': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/aws_lambda_powertools-1.24.0.dist-info': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/numpy-1.21.5.dist-info': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/boto3-1.18.65.dist-info': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/wrapt-1.13.3.dist-info': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/idna-3.3.dist-info': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/pytz-2021.3.dist-info': No such file or directory
  find: '/root/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/a92be47b63e9e4444f3ed7b447b3a846a5de81273cb952775bb672275a820a07_slspyc/six-1.16.0.dist-info': No such file or directory
  
      at /codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:331:13
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at installRequirements (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:318:28)
      at installRequirementsIfNeeded (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:576:3)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:655:29)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.tryCatcher (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/codebuild/output/src472528929/src/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```